# Is there an ATM before the VOA desk at Batam Center harbor?

Tags: visas, money, singapore, indonesia

We intend to travel from Singapore to Indonesia by ferry. If you intend to (keep open the option to) extend your stay you need to purchase a Visa on Arrival. Purchasing a Visa on Arrival is **I think** done in local currency in cash. Should we withdraw money in Singapore and exchange it, or is there a more efficient option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been to Batam many times. I haven't seen any ATM before immigration (last visit before covid times). Its better to exchange required amount for immigration from Singapore itself. There are money exchange vendors in harborfront terminal itself.

Even if there is an ATM, you should not count on it, as it can be out of order, or your card may not work.

Comment: +1, but back in the days when I used to need Indonesian VOAs, they could also be paid for in foreign currencies.  The exchange rates were pretty terrible though.

Comment: I, too, would presume the exchange rate would be less than favorable if there were an ATM at the harbor. The exchange rates at airports seem to follow this pattern.

Comment: Just went through the process: there is indeed no ATM, the exchange rates at harbourfront were surprisingly reasonable, and the VOA process was decently easy (for the record, we didn't need a flight out of Indonesia).